# Flutter error: "The method 'Transaction' isn't defined for the type 'MyHomePage' "

Tags: flutter, dart, transactions

I just want to use transactions, but I saw this error. I looked in the Flutter documentation and didn't find anything useful. I am using [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code). I use the Maximilian Schwarzmüller tutorial (2022), and I’m surprised how fast Flutter changes!

Is there a link for this document? Did the name of this structure change?

And here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter App',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Transaction> transactions = [
    Transaction(
      id: 't1',
      Title: 'Weekly Shoes',
      amount: 69.99,
      date: DateTime.now(),
    ),
    Transaction(
      id: 't2',
      Title: 'Weekly Groceries',
      amount: 16.53,
      date: DateTime.now(),
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter App'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Card(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Text('Chart!'),
              elevation: 5,
            ),
          ),
          Card(
            child: Text('List of TX!'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Am I using an old structure?

Comment: you are not importing the `Transaction` model

Comment: there is nothing look like 'Transaction model' in flutter package. are u sure we have such a thing in there ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> It looks like the code you provided is missing the definition for the Transaction class, which is causing the error. The Transaction class is not a built-in Flutter class, so you need to define it yourself. From the usage in your code, it seems like the Transaction class might be a custom class to represent transactions with properties like id, Title, amount, and date.

=> To fix the error, you need to define the Transaction class before using it in your code. Here's an example of how you can define the Transaction class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter App',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}



class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Transaction> transactions = [
    Transaction(
      id: 't1',
      title: 'Weekly Shoes',
      amount: 69.99,
      date: DateTime.now(),
    ),
    Transaction(
      id: 't2',
      title: 'Weekly Groceries',
      amount: 16.53,
      date: DateTime.now(),
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter App'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Card(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Text('Chart!'),
              elevation: 5,
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            children: transactions.map((transaction) {
              return Card(
                child: Text(transaction.title),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> Create outside code transaction class

```
 class Transaction {
      final String id;
      final String title;
      final double amount;
      final DateTime date;
    
      Transaction({
        required this.id,
        required this.title,
        required this.amount,
        required this.date,
      });
    }
```

> In this example, I've defined the Transaction class with properties id, title, amount, and date. Then, I created a List called transactions with two sample transaction objects. The MyHomePage widget displays the transactions in a column using Card widgets.

Comment: i write my code just like my instructor. it works for him. and i thought it is a built-in class. are you sure about that?

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT